# разделить DocumentRoot, отдельные структуры файлов

Tags: php, linux, apache, веб-сервер

Дано: у нас в компании несколько сайтов, у каждого сайта свой *DocumentRoot*.

```
/var/www/site1/htdocs

/var/www/site2/public

/var/www/site3/publc_html
```

Если в *DocumentRoot* одного из сайтов положить файл `test.php` 
с несколькими строчками кода:

```
printf('<pre>%s</pre>', print_r(scandir('/'), TRUE));

echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
```

мы получим файловую структура сервера:

```
Array
(
    [0] => .
    [1] => ..
    [2] => var
    [3] => etc
    ...
)
```

и адрес текущего скрипта:

```
/var/www/site1/htdocs/test.php
```

Логично предположить, что *DocumentRoot* другого сайта лежит рядом,
и мы можем попробовать получить доступ к файлам другого сайта

```
printf('<pre>%s</pre>', print_r(scandir('/var/www/site2/public'), TRUE));

Array
(
    [0] => .
    [1] => ..
    [2] => index.php
    ...
)
```

Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы у каждого сайта было свое файловое пространство (файловая система), чтобы *DocumentRoot* каждого сайта совпадал с корнем файловой системы, и, таким образом, файлы одного сайта  не будут иметь доступ к файлам другого сайта и к файлам операционной системы сервера?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> как сделать так, чтобы файлы одного сайта не будут иметь доступ к файлам другого сайта

Один из вариантов

1. Всех юзеров добавляем в одну группу
2. На папку site[1-3] ставим chmod 701 и chown user:group каждую под своим юзером.
3. ставим php-fpm и поднимаем для каждого юзера свой пул со своим сокетом

В итоге пхп-фпм и энжинкс читают файлы юзера, а другие юзеры - нет.

> чтобы DocumentRoot каждого сайта совпадал с корнем файловой системы

chroot
но это, кстати, не так чтобы обязательно.

Ещё один вариант - это если железа много - виртуализация. OpenVZ например. Каждому сайту по виртуалке.